# Strategy pattern in C++. Implementation options

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, shared-ptr, strategy-pattern

Here's a simplified example of what is called (I hope - please, correct me if I'm wrong) *Strategy* pattern: there's a class `FileWriter` which writes key-value pairs to a file and uses object of `IFormatter` interface for formatting text being written. There are different formatters implementations and formatter object is passed when `FileWriter` is created.
Here's one (bad) implementation of such pattern:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

class IFormatter {
  public:
    virtual string format(string key, double value) = 0;
};

class JsonFormatter : public IFormatter {
  public:
    string format(string key, double value) { 
        stringstream ss;
        ss << "\""+key+"\": " << value;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

class TabFormatter : public IFormatter {
  public:
    string format(string key, double value) { 
        stringstream ss;
        ss << key+"\t" << value;
        return ss.str();
    }
};

class FileWriter {
  public:  
    FileWriter(string fname, IFormatter& fmt):fmt_(fmt)
    {
        f_.open(fname.c_str(), ofstream::out);
    }

    void writePair(string key, double value)
    {
        f_ << fmt_.format(key, value);
    }

  private:
    ofstream f_;
    IFormatter& fmt_;
};
```

As can be seen, the main drawback of such approach is it's **unreliability** - `Formatter` object passed to `FileWriter` has to exist during whole `FileWriter`'s lifetime, thus calls like `FileWriter("test.txt", JsonFormatter())` lead directly to `SegFault`.

In this regard, I'd like to discuss what could be the other options for implementing such an approach with "easy-to-use" and simplicity requirements:

- either new formatter can be passed when file writer is created, or
- existing formatter can be passed and used.

I came up with several alternatives described below with their drawbacks (IMO):

- **templates:** having `FileWriter` as a template class which takes exact `FormatterClass` as an argument; *drawback:* ugly to call: `FileWriter<JsonFormatter>("test.txt", JsonFormatter())` - here, `JsonFormatter` is typed twice.
- **raw pointers:** `FileWriter("test.txt", new JsonFormatter())`; *drawback* - who should delete formatter object? `FileWriter`? if yes, then passing an address of existing formatter will lead to `SegFault` once `FileWriter` object attempts to delete formatter.
- **shared pointers:** `FileWriter("test.txt", dynamic_pointer_cast<IFormatter*>(shared_ptr<JsonFormatter*>(new JsonFormatter()))`; *drawback:* ugly to call, and again, what if formatter was created before creating file writer?

What would be the best practices here?

**UPDATE**

In response to answers that suggested to use `std::function` - What if Formatter may store a state (say, precision) and have additional methods, like `getHeader()`, for instance, for CSV files?

Additionaly, storing `IFormatter` by value isn't possible since it's an abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to use:

```
JsonFormatter formatter;
FileWriter writer("test.txt", formatter);
// Use writer.
```

The other option that is a little bit better is to have a `clone()` function in `IFormatter`. Then, `FileWriter` can clone the object, take ownership of the clone and delete it in its destructor.

```
 class IFormatter {
   public:
     virtual string format(string key, double value) = 0;
     virtual IFormatter* clone() const = 0;
 };


 class FileWriter {
   public:  

     FileWriter(string fname, IFormatter const& fmt):fmt_(fmt.clone())
     {
         f_.open(fname.c_str(), ofstream::out);
     }

     ~FileWriter()
     {
        delete fmt_;
     }

     void writePair(string key, double value)
     {
         f_ << fmt_->format(key, value);
     }

   private:
     ofstream f_;
     IFormatter* fmt_;
 };
```

Now, you can call `FileWriter` with temporary object too.

```
FileWriter writer("test.txt", JsonFormatter());
// Use writer.
```

Comment: while this solution will work, indeed, the design described in question seems to me more like a general approach which should be supported by language/standard library capabilities (or require a different design/pattern) rather than require a programmer to explicitly handle it by writing `clone()` methods for his classes.

Answer (score 1):

> templates: having FileWriter as a template class which takes exact FormatterClass as an argument; drawback: ugly to call: FileWriter("test.txt", JsonFormatter()) - here, JsonFormatter is typed twice.

More templates!

```
template<class Formatter> 
FileWriter<Formatter> makeFileWriter(const std::string& filename, const Formatter& formatter) 
{return FileWriter<Formatter>(filename, formatter);}
```

Ta da!  Now it's as simple as:

```
auto fileWriter = makeFileWriter("test.txt", JSonFormatter());`
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! I'll still try to refrain from using templates for now, unless I'll find a suitable solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the standard library does (e.g. `std::shared_ptr` can take a deleter). `Formatter` must be copy constructible, and obviously the expression `f << fmt(key, value)` must be well-formed.

```
class FileWriter {
public:
    template<typename Formatter>
    FileWriter(std::string fname, Formatter fmt) :
        fmt(fmt)
    {
        f.open(fname.c_str(), std::ofstream::out);
    }

    void writePair(std::string key, double value)
    {
        f << fmt(key, value);
    }

private:
    std::ofstream f;
    std::function<std::string (std::string, double)> fmt;
};
```

If you need more than one function in your interface, you can use your original approach but control the lifetime of the formatter with `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` (remember to make the destructor virtual).

```
struct Formatter
{
    virtual ~Formatter() {}
    virtual std::string format(std::string key, double value) = 0;
};

class FileWriter {
public:
    FileWriter(std::string fname, std::unique_ptr<Formatter>&& fmt_)
    {
        if (!fmt_)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("Formatter cannot be null");
        }

        f.open(fname.c_str(), std::ofstream::out);

        fmt = std::move(fmt_); // strong exception safety guarantee
    }

    void writePair(std::string key, double value)
    {
        f << fmt->format(key, value);
    }

private:
    std::ofstream f;
    std::unique_ptr<Formatter> fmt;
};
```

If you want to pass an existing `Formatter` to the `FileWriter`, you either need to copy/move it into a smart pointer to transfer ownership, or you need to wrap it in the formatter interface.

```
class FormatterProxy : public Formatter
{
public:
    FormatterProxy(Formatter& fmt) :
        fmt(fmt)
    {
    }

    std::string format(std::string key, double value)
    {
      return fmt.format(key, value);
    }

private:
  Formatter& fmt;
};
```

This still has the lifetime management issue you are trying to avoid.
However, I do not see any way around this. Either you give unique or shared ownership of the `Formatter` to the `FileWriter`, or you leave lifetime management in the hands the caller (which is a perfectly valid approach if you value efficiency over safety).

Comment: same comment as for @Yakk's answer - what if `IFormatter` has to carry a state (say, precision for double) or may have additional methods (like, `getHeader()` for CSV files formatting)? Should there be a different design?

Comment: As long as `Formatter` is copy constructible, there is no reason it cannot carry state. If you need additional methods, you could either pass a formatter which implements `operator()`, or wrap your formatter in a lambda: `[formatter](std::string s, double d) { return formatter.format(s, d); }` (here, either make `format` `const` or the lambda `mutable`).

Comment: @peetonn I think I know what you mean w.r.t. extra methods. I have updated my answer. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
using IFormatter - std::function<std::string(std::string,double)>;
```

Your formatter should be a function, not an interface.

Callers can use `std::ref` if they want to guarantee lifetime, wrap a shared ptr if they want nebulous lifetime, or pass by-value.

If you want a richer interface, you can either take a pile of such, or write a class that is a pile of such (either via inheritance or by writing `notstd::functions` manually).

Store `IFormatter fmt;` by-value, use `fmt(a,b)` instead of `fmt.format(a,b)` (DRY!).  Client code can make it ref or smart semantics if it wants.

inheritance as an implementation detail, instead of driving your design, is freeing.

Comment: why it should be a function? what if formatter should save some state, say, precision for doubles which is specified during formatter construction?

Comment: @peet std function can do that.

Comment: storing `IFromatter` by value isn't possible - as it's an abstract class. regarding using `std::function` I don't think it applies to this case - formatter can have other methods as well (in my more complex case, formatter has method `getHeader()` which returns a header for CSV files for instance).

Comment: @peetonn My `IFormatter` works by value.  Yours does not.  That is a problem with your solution, hence your lifetime management headaches.  If you want to get rid of lifetime management headaches baked into your solution, stop baking pointers into your interfaces: pointers (and references) *imply* lifetime management headaches.  Your actual use case, not reflected in the OP, would require a bit more work to use type erasure on, but it is quite doable.  Your belief that `std::function` cannot store state is ... incorrect.  Generalizations of `std::function` solve your general problem.