# How to properly design and implement CopyConstructable interface in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, interface, copy-constructor

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952765/strategy-pattern-in-c-implementation-options) was a precursor to the current one. Need to come up with better OOP design.

**Problem desription:** there is a class called `FileWriter` which uses object of class `Formatter` to write a dictionary of key-values (`std::map<std::string, double>`) into a file.

**Requirements:**

1. Initialize `FileWriter` with existing formatters:

```
    JsonFormatter jf;
    FileWriter fw("test.txt", jf);
```

2. Initialize `FileWriter` with r-values:

```
    FileFormatter fw("test.txt", CsvFormatter());
```

3. There should be a hierarchy of `Formatter` classes (derived from interface `IFormatter`) to allow the following:

```
    {
        CsvFormatter cf(2, "\t"); // 2 digits precision, tab-separated
        FileWriter fwCsv("test.txt", csv);
    }
    {
        JsonFormatter jf(2, true); // 2 digits precision, compact JSON formatting
        FileWriter fwJson("test.txt", jf);
    }
```

4. `Formatter` may store additional parameters such as precision, separator symbol (for CSV) or compact formatting flag (for JSON).

What would be the proper design pattern and correct implementation for such problem? My main concerns are:

- `FileFormatter` should store a pointer to `IFormatter` (base class) because it'll be abstract class
- Having a pointer to `IFormatter` will require passing pointers in `FileWriter` constructor, which will impose additional implementation complexity in order to meet requirement 1

How it's done currently in C++? Does this case fall under [source/sink](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Move_Constructor) idiom? Any links for existing solutions are welcome as well.